# My printer has jobs waiting but does not print

Tags: printing, printer, cups

I would like to print files using a terminal.

To do so I use the following command :

```
lp myfile.txt -d MyPrinter
```

The printer does not print anything but when I enter `lpstat -o` I have the following result:

```
MyPrinter-18 username 5120 wed. 13 february. 2019 10:09:53 CET
MyPrinter-19 username 5120 wed. 13 february. 2019 10:08:53 CET
MyPrinter-20 username 5120 wed. 13 february. 2019 10:10:53 CET
```

The result of `lpstat -t` is:

```
scheduler not running
no system default destination
device for MyPrinter: ipp://localhost:631/printers/MyPrinter

MyPrinter accepting requests since wed 13 February 2019 10:02:06 CET

MyPrinter now printing MyPrinter-15. enable since 13 February...
Waiting jobs to complete

MyPrinter-18 username 5120 wed. 13 february. 2019 10:09:53 CET
MyPrinter-19 username 5120 wed. 13 february. 2019 10:08:53 CET
MyPrinter-20 username 5120 wed. 13 february. 2019 10:10:53 CET
```

Why won't my printer print the files?

EDIT : it's a new printer so I am wondering if the problem comes from the installation of the printer itself on the machine. I have no graphical view on the machine and I am a bit lost with the ppd file story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was doing wrong. To install the printer, I used the **lpdamin** command but I was using the wrong uri.

To find out what uri I should use I had to use **hp-setup -i** and it displayed the uri to use.

I was then able to add my printer as follow :

```
lpadmin -p MyPrinter -E -v correct_uri -P ppd_file.ppd
```